# « Sur proposition (de) » avec l'adjectif « écologiste » pour l'animé : un cas unique ou usuel ?

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, locutions, politique

> Repas exclusivement végétariens dans les cantines deux fois par
>   semaine, transformation du périphérique en boulevard urbain,
>   «découverture» du canal Saint-Martin ou création d'une régie de
>   l'énergie renouvelable parisienne seront étudiés sur proposition
>   écologiste.
>
> [ *Paris adopte son plan climat et vise le retrait de tous les
>   véhicules diesel*, ds. [La presse](http://www.lapresse.ca/environnement/201711/20/01-5144199-paris-adopte-son-plan-climat-et-vise-le-retrait-de-tous-les-vehicules-diesel.php), de l'AFP. ]

J'imagine qu'on peut réaménager la phrase en disant que *les écologistes ont proposé d'étudier l'idée des [...]*, par exemple ?

- La locution prépositive [*sur proposition de*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/proposition) pour « d'après
  l'avis de ; sur la suggestion de » (Ac.9), avec l'ellipse de la
  préposition *de* et avec un adjectif plutôt qu'un nom, tel que dans
  l'article, est-ce courant ?
- Retrouve-t-on le même phénomène avec [*recommandation*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/recommandation) ou *suggestion*  ; avec un autre mot en locution avec *sur* ?
- Quel adjectif autre qu'*écologiste* serait couramment associé à l'une
  ou l'autre locution dans ce genre de contexte (les intervenants en politique etc.) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. La locution prépositive sur proposition de pour « d'après l'avis de ; sur la suggestion de » (Ac.9), avec l'ellipse de la préposition de et avec un adjectif plutôt qu'un nom, tel que dans l'article, est-ce courant ?

Oui, c'est assez courant.

> 2. Retrouve-t-on le même phénomène avec recommandation ou suggestion ; avec un autre mot en locution avec sur ?

Oui, par exemple *sur **recommandation/suggestion/décision/ordonnance/convocation/**... royale/présidentielle/...*

> 3. Quel adjectif autre qu'écologiste serait couramment associé à l'une ou l'autre locution dans ce genre de contexte (les intervenants en politique etc.) ?

En voici quelques-uns avec *proposition*:

> [***Sur proposition socialiste**, il ne sera plus possible pour les personnes morales de garantir les prêts consentis à des partis ou groupements politiques*.](http://www.lcp.fr/actualites/les-deputes-se-penchent-sur-linterdiction-des-emplois-familiaux-au-parlement) 27 juillet 2017 - LCP
>
> [***Sur proposition communiste**, cette présomption fut abrogée en 2000 à l’occasion des lois Aubry mais réintroduite en 2003 par une loi Fillon.*](http://www.assemblee-nationale.fr/14/propositions/pion4413.asp) 25 janvier 2017 - Assemblée nationale
>
> [*...ceux qui ont abrogé le « Glass-Seagall Act » et le « Shad-Johnson Juridictional Act » signés par Clinton **sur proposition républicaine***.](http://cochonsurterre.blogspot.fr/2009/05/cent-jours-dobama-et-apres-waterloo.html?m=0) mai 2009 - Blog
>
> ***Sur proposition conservatrice**, la Chambre. Haute a décidé de prendre des vacances jusqu'au. 9 septembre.* 1947 - Suisse
>
> [*Enfin les autres sièges du bureau sont attribués au 1er tour de scrutin (majorité absolue)  à Elisabeth Chatelain **sur proposition socialiste** (75 voix), à Charles Selleger **sur proposition radicale** (65 voix) et à Eric Bertinat sur proposition de l’UDC (65 voix).*](https://www.verts-ge.ch/nos-idees/echos-du-grand-conseil/item/523-session-des-5-6-novembre-2009.html#.WhVIEUqnHcs) novembre 2009 - Les Verts , Genève

Un adjectif comme *conjointe* ou *motivée* peut aussi suivre *proposition*, mais il est alors suivi de la préposition *de*:

> *Le Président de la République, sur proposition du Gouvernement pendant la durée des sessions ou **sur proposition conjointe des deux assemblées**, publiées au Journal officiel, peut soumettre au référendum tout projet de loi portant sur l’organisation des pouvoirs publics...* - Article 11 de la Constitution française
>
> ***Sur proposition motivée d'un tiers des États membres**, du Parlement européen ou de la Commission européenne, le Conseil, statuant à la majorité des quatre cinquièmes de ses membres après approbation du Parlement européen, peut constater qu'il existe un risque clair de violation grave par un État membre des valeurs visées à l'article 2.* - Article 7 du traité de l'Union européenne

sauf ici:

> ***Sur proposition conjointe socialiste-UDF** propose 3 sièges pour la première circonscription et 5 sièges pour la deuxième* - Bulletin de l'union des français de l'étranger - 1989

Comment: Merci ! J'ai trouvé l'exemple de la Suisse plus usuel, et je me rends compte que c'est beaucoup l'absence d'adéquation chez moi entre l'adjectif et la référence à un parti politique connu qui fait que je peux trouver ça moins usuel dans certains cas, comme écologiste ou même socialiste i.e. en politique fédérale au Canada c'est surtout l'affaire des Libéraux et des Conservateurs. Pour vous le fait de savoir que c'est un parti politique ou un groupe de gens ou d'intervenants qui pensent d'une manière ou dont l'action se qualifie de cette manière, c'est basé sur la connaissance générale.../2

Comment: de la politique intérieure de la République ou vous avez des repères linguistiques ? _Sur proposition écologiste_, c'est un parti ou un groupe ça ? Merci !

Comment: Félicitations pour le 40k, une première !